# Remove icon from the toolbar

Tags: gnome, icons, gnome-classic, ambiance, faenza

**Basic Specs** - Ubuntu 13.10, Gnome 3 (session fallback), Ambiance theme, Faenza icons.

I tried to drag and drop Transmission icon to place it in the desktop and it appeared on the top toolbar instead and i don't know how to remove it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, or <kbd>Super</kbd> while dragging it.